# R difference between stat_smooth and lm (using log) in power regression?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have some data:

```
library(ggplot2)    
x <-c(2600248.25,1303899.14285714,1370136.33333333,353105.857142857, 145446.952380952,299032,75142.2631578947,40381.1818181818,6133.93103448276,975.234567901235,779.341463414634)
    y <- c(4,7,6,14,21,9,19,22,29,81,41)
```

Which I am trying to make a regression on and plot. My issue is that I want to make a regression and plot it against my data, but when I use lm on the log values, predict and plot I get some different results compared to stat_smooth. Considering the code:

```
    fit0 <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
    summary(fit0)

    newx <- x
    lm.fit <- predict(fit0, newdata = data.frame(x=newx), interval = "confidence")
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,lm.fit))

    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula ="y~x") + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()

p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=fit)) # result too low
p <- p +  geom_line(aes(y=10^fit)) # result too high
```

As seen, I have tried both with the log result and converting back using 10^x. As is, the two linear models should show the same values? What is wrong here, how do I get the correct values?

(my end goals is to be able to plot prediction intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `log10` scale on `ggplot` but `log` for the calculation. In R only using `log()` means you are using the natural logarithm. When you use `log10()` instead, you see there is no difference in `geom_smooth` and `lm`. Since `ggplot` is just calling the `lm` routine, the output is expected as same.

```
library(ggplot2)    
x <-c(2600248.25,1303899.14285714,1370136.33333333,353105.857142857, 145446.952380952,299032,75142.2631578947,40381.1818181818,6133.93103448276,975.234567901235,779.341463414634)
y <- c(4,7,6,14,21,9,19,22,29,81,41)

fit0 <- lm(log10(y) ~ log10(x))
summary(fit0)

newx <- x
fit <- predict(fit0, newdata = data.frame(x=newx), interval = "confidence")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula ="y~x") + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
p <- p +  geom_line(aes(y=10^fit[,1])) 
p
```

The black and blue line are overlapping, so it's hard to see. Still, this is the output graph:
[image: output]

---

For further information, check the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/log).

> `log` computes logarithms, by default natural logarithms, `log10` computes
>   common (i.e., base 10) logarithms, and `log2` computes binary (i.e.,
>   base 2) logarithms. The general form `log(x, base)` computes logarithms
>   with base base.

Comment: Thanks! The lacking use of `log10` was the exact issue! Reminder to self `ln = log`. I guess I'm used to `ln` from other programs. Having read the documentation, it makes perfect sense to have it as `log`.

Answer (score 1):

Run this code, I hope this will answer your question,

making the model

```
model=lm(y~x,df)
```

predicting the y value from the model that we made and assigning to predicted

```
predicted<-predict(model,newdata = x.df)
```

making the plot for bothe predicted and the real value of x

`p<-ggplot(df, aes(x))+ scale_x_log10()+ geom_smooth(method='lm', aes(y=y), col='red')`

this line makes the real value or original plot

adding the predicted point or data to the same graph

```
p<- p+ geom_smooth(method='lm', aes(y=predicted), col='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good answer if you would like to fit a linear model, to something that is otherwise (in my case) not linear in nature. That is why I `log` transformed the axis. Hence it wouldn't work in my case.